# Laravel and Mailgun

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I am trying to set up emailing feature on my laravel project. I got everything settled up but somehow I get this error

Swift_TransportException
Cannot send message without a sender address.

Here is my mail.php script.

```
'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
    ],

    'mailgun' => [
        'transport' => 'mailgun',
    ],

    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ],

    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],

    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],
],
```

.env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox*****************.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********************************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

ReportInfrastructure.php

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ReportInfrastructure extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('infor@mise.gov.ki')
                    ->markdown('emails.infrastructure');
    }
}
```

infrastructure.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# Critical Infrastructure Name

PLEASE NOTE: You're receiving this email because our records indicate that above Infrastructure is in critical condition and need to address asap.

Click the on the button below to show more details of this issue.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Route

```
Route::get('/email', function () {

    Mail::to('email@email.com')->send(new ReportInfrastructure());

    return new ReportInfrastructure();
 });
```

Can someone point me out what I did wrong?

Comment: you have not posted the most important part, the Mail class and the method that is sending the mail, so please post those

Comment: @Berto99 sorry I thought it was part of my post but I missed it out. I have edited my question to reflect on what you commented on. Thanks

Comment: you are still missing the method that is creating the email

Comment: Web.php is missing, I just added

Comment: have you tried `php artisan cache:clear` or `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: I tried that and another error popped up
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                            
  Class 'Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider' not found
I really hope it's not related to email function I m working on.

Comment: you need to isolate the problem, so instead of returning an Infrastructure, just put `return 'works';` and see, why do you have to complicate the life when you are testing new features

Comment: Ok so instead of this `return new ReportInfrastructure();` I will have this `return 'works'` in web.php

Comment: Yes, then see if there are errors, and if there are, than there is something wrong on the email

Comment: Thanks, problem solved with mailtrap. I was having problem as I didn't verify my account on mailgun as I can't received a code to my phone. our telephone provider block a few verification system including mailgun.